# Difference between cores and logical processors

Tags: process, cpu, thread, multiprocessor

I have a question about core and logical processors. So, my computer has 1 CPU with 2 cores and 4 logical processors. Does this mean that my computer has 4 threads, 2 threads for every core? Than why it says 2975 Threads if I have only 4?

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: This does not seem directly related to the use or administration of any Unix system. Is your question related to some issue that you are trying to resolve? If not, we may want to migrate this question to the [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) site.

Answer (score 2):

This distinction between cores and threads exists because of the design of some CPUs.

Intel introduced a technology called [Hyper-Threading](https://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/gaming/resources/hyper-threading.html) in some of their CPUs.  This takes advantage of some of the internal workings of CPUs where the flow of execution can be suddenly forced to wait, eg: for data to load from RAM into the CPU.  Instead of forcing the core to waste time just waiting for IO, Hyper-Threading seeks to use the core to do something else useful.

To do this they introduced a concept of "logical processors".  The same silicon is used by multiple (usually 3) processors.  While one is waiting the other is using the same circuitry to process.

So a processor (chip plugged onto the motherboard) might have two cores with four logical cores.  To the operating system this looks a lot like having 4 CPUs.  Electronically two CPU cores are each pretending to be two.

---

It's worth understanding that two logical processors on the same core will frequently wait for each other.  So two logical processors on one core is not equivalent on performance as two separate cores.

There are even certain circumstances where Hyper-Threading is known to reduce overall performance with two logical processors collectively achieving less than one single core could.  Very high memory IO is supposedly one of these cases.

---

Threads are a programming concept.  However many logical processors you have you can have many more threads.  Threads a time sliced: they run for a few milli seconds and are then paused by the operating system so that another thread can run.

Having four logical processors means that the operating system can ask the CPU(s) to run four threads at the same time.

Comment: Technically the Intel SMT implementation was developed by … Digital!

Comment: @StephenKitt are you referring to multi core or hyper threading?

Comment: Hyperthreading is an implementation of SMT (simultaneous multi-threading). Digital were working on it for Alpha, and there was an Alpha chip with multi-threading but it got canned after the Compaq acquisition before it could be commercialised. The lead engineer ended up at Intel and applied the Alpha SMT technology to the Pentium 4. (Alpha tech ended up all over the place, follow the engineers...)

Answer (score 0):

A core is a unit of the CPU which can do all the operations (addition, substraction, multiplication…) on your data.

A logical CPU analyses the current program and pilots the core when computation are needed. We can have a core shared by multiple logical CPU. In such a case, some thread could sleep the time to perform a computation on the core if 2 logical CPU need the core at the same time.